# Using Linq how do get a list of users and their last login from two tables

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a list of users and and their last login date.

I need to display the following columns

```
User Name
First Name
Last Name
Last Login Date
Role
Is Active
```

I'm having difficulty because the data is split between two tables:
User table:

```
Users
    UserId
    UserName
    FirstName
    LastName
    Role
    IsActive
```

And LogonHistory table

```
LogonHistory
    Id
    Username
    LoginDate
```

I have tried using `Join`,`group`, and `max`but it only lets me use properties from the logonhistory table.

Here's an example of my `join`query:

```
var users = db.Users
    .Join(db.LogonHistory, user => user.UserName, logon => logon.Username, (user, logon) => new UserSearchResults
    {
        UserName = user.UserName,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
        Email = user.Email,
        IsActive = user.Active,
        LoginHistory = logon.LoginDate
    });
```

Here's an example of my `group`ing query:

```
    var loginHistory = from l in db.LogonHistory
                        join u in db.Users on l.Username equals u.UserName
                        group l by l.Username into grp
                        let LastLoginDate = grp.Max(d => d.LoginDate)
                        from l in grp
                        where l.LoginDate == LastLoginDate
                        select l;
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or recommend a better method?

EDIT:
Essentially what I need to do is `Join` the User table and LogonHistory table on the Username and return the user's details and the latest login date.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes, I am using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lastlogins = from h in db.LogonHistory
                       group h by h.UserName into hgroup
                       select new
                       {
                           UserName = hgroup.Key,
                           LastLoginDate = hgroup.Max(x => x.LoginDate)
                       };

        var query = from u in db.Users
                    join h in lastlogins on u.UserName equals h.Username 
                    select new
                    {
                        u.UserName,
                        u.FirstName,
                        u.LastName,
                        u.Role,
                        u.IsActive,
                        h.LastLoginDate
                    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use navigation properties instead. Your query would be like:

```
var loginHistory= db.Users.Select(user => new UserSearchResults
                                    {
                                        UserName = user.UserName,
                                        FirstName = user.FirstName,
                                        LastName = user.LastName,
                                        Email = user.Email,
                                        IsActive = user.Active,
                                        LastLoginDate=user.LogonHistory
                                                          .OrderByDescending(e=>e.LoginDate)
                                                          .FirstOrDefault().LoginDate
                                     });
```

Comment: I understand now what you were doing. I'm not getting the right result though because when the tables were created the LogonHistory and Users weren't associated via Primary Key so EF can't do `user.LogonHistory`. It's a great answer though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using EntityFramework :

```
var loginHistory = db.Users.select(e => new {
   e.UserName,
   e.FirstName,
   e.LastName,
   e.Role,
   e.IsActive,
   e.LogonHistory.OrderByDescending(ee=>ee.LoginDate).FirstOrDefault().LoginDate
});
```

Comment: the problem with your solution is EF can retrieve `LogonHistory` associated with an user in any particular order, there is not guarantee that comes in the same order they were inserted, that's why I use the order by